# What can cause "jsf is not defined" error in browser console

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Hi I got a simple fresh project based on MyFaces 2.0.11 with Primefaces 3.0 on Tomcat 6

When I'm trying to navigate to a page I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsf is not defined` error which directs me to a ref in my js code `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` ... (which is reasonable cause I'm trying to use the jsf.js and it's not event present I'm my page..)

And if I do view source of my page I dont the the include of the `jsf.js` file

Now if I add it manually like this

`<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>`

every thing works just fine... but I prefer not to include it manually , Instead I would like to know what are the reasons that can cause the lack of the jsf.js in my page

I google for a while and none of the similar case represents mine

I do have `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` My page is really simple...

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you have a h:head on your page the script *should* be there. Check if it isn't skipped somehow by putting eg a title inside it.

Comment: Added title... title is being display properly but the jsf.js still isn't being added...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script will only be auto-included whenever you use [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) in the view. If you don't, then it won't be auto-included.

Just add an extra check before you call `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`:

```
if (typeof jsf !== 'undefined') {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(someFunctionName);
}
```

Or, explicitly include the library by `<h:outputScript>` on the proper `library`, like as you already did.

Comment: @BalusC I used this method to try to circumvent the same error, to no avail. I still get the same message, and I've confirmed that the script is formed correctly on the client with this check.